# Mesh Deformer Modifier - Low poly mesh with softbody simulation deforming a high poly mesh

Tags: physics, parent, soft-body, origin

Is it possible in Blender to optimise the softbody simulation by using a low poly mesh for the simulation to deform a high poly mesh? Instead of simulating the high poly mesh itself which would take much longer.
Just as it is possible in Cinema4D: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CykigKQwadU
I've tried to set it up in Blender but I can't parent the high poly mesh to low poly. Well, actually I can but it doesn't move with the low poly mesh due to the origin point of the low poly mesh staying in the same place during the softbody simulation. The result is kind of fancy but obviously it's not how it should look.
[image: image showing my results]

Any ideas how to make it work in the correct way?
Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parenting only effects the origin and the transforms of the object, never the mesh. There are two ways to achieve this however. 
1. Lattice: you can use a lattice modifier, which can be given a softbody component
2. More practical: Mesh deform modifier. It's a bit cumbersome to set it up, but I'm sure you'll find help with that online.

Comment: Well, as I've mentioned above, I've already set up the mesh deform modifier but the high poly mesh doesn't follow the low poly softbody mesh which results in the way shown in the picture above, which isn't satysfying at all. :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't see anything about a modifier in your post. Anyways, from a quick look I would guess your cage did not envelop the entire object when you pressed bind.

Comment: Thank you, that was the case. I've forgotten that it doesn't work in a way like surface deform modifier.